# EMR auto terminate cluster not completing spark application?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, aws-cli, amazon-emr

I intend to create an auto terminating EMR cluster that executes a spark cluster and shuts down.

If I submit the application as a step to an existing cluster that does not auto terminate using the following command, it works and application completes in 3 minutes.

```
aws emr add-steps --cluster-id xxx \
--steps Name=imdbetlapp,Jar=command-runner.jar,Args=\
[spark-submit,--deploy-mode,cluster,--master,yarn,--conf,spark.yarn.submit.waitAppCompletion=true,\
--py-files,s3://bucketname/etl_module.zip,\
--files,s3://bucketname/etl_module/aws_config.cfg,\
s3://bucketname/run_etl.py],ActionOnFailure=CONTINUE --region us-east-1
```

However, when i use the following command to create an auto terminating cluster with a step function, the application keeps running for more that 30 minutes.

```
aws emr create-cluster --applications Name=Hadoop Name=Spark --use-default-roles \
--bootstrap-actions Path=s3://bucketname/emr_bootstrap.sh,Name=installPython \
--log-uri s3://logbucketname/elasticmapreduce/ \
--configurations https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucketname/emr_configurations.json \
--steps Name=imdbetlapp,Jar=command-runner.jar,Args=[spark-submit,--deploy-mode,cluster,\
--master,yarn,--conf,spark.yarn.submit.waitAppCompletion=true,\
--py-files,s3://bucketname/etl_module,\
--files,s3://bucketname/etl_module/aws_config.cfg,s3://bucketname/run_etl.py] \
--release-label emr-5.29.0 --instance-groups InstanceGroupType=MASTER,InstanceCount=1,InstanceType=m4.large \
InstanceGroupType=CORE,InstanceCount=1,InstanceType=m4.large \
--auto-terminate --region us-east-1
```

What am I missing out?

I have zipped my etl python module and uploaded that along with the actual folder and configuration file `aws_config.cfg`. It works perfectly if submitted as a step function to existing cluster as I can see output being written to another S3 bucket. However, if I issue a CLI command to create a cluster and execute the step the step keeps executing forever.

Comment: enable debugging logs to s3 and check out the logs

Comment: Have you considered the time taken to launch the cluster?